# Polarization of the Jacobian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, riemann-surfaces

I'm walking towards the Torelli's Theorem.I started from scratch! I did not even know what a divisor was in a Riemann surface. I currently went through Abel's Theorem, theta divisor... Now I am reading the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem 2.25: The theta divisor $\Theta$ of the Jacobian variety $J(R)$, the subvariety $W^{g-1}$ and Riemann's constant are related by following equality:

$\Theta=W^{g-1} + [k]$.

In the reference I'm using [https://www.amazon.com/Advances-Moduli-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821821563](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821563)

After this theorem 2.25 is written: This theorem implies that the polarization of the Jacobian variety 
is given by the line bundle $[W^{g-1}]$.

I need to read about polarization of the Jacobian variety. Right now I have another very good reference $compact $  $riemann$ $ surfaces$  $ Raghavan $ $Narasimhan$, But I did not find out about polarization of the Jacobian variety in this book.

I would like references on the subject. Thank you!